# Disable background:url(...) encoding as base64 in Minify package

Tags: css, npm, base64, node-modules, minify

I use [minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify?activeTab=readme) to minimize my `js` and `css` files. But after minimizing the files, the ones which contain `background:url(...)` become larger, because the url is encoded to `base64`.

I want to turn off this [css-base64-images](https://github.com/Filirom1/css-base64-images) function. But according to an [issue](https://github.com/coderaiser/minify/issues/40#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20such%20way.%20minify%20not%20customizable%3A%20it%20is%20it%27s%20pros%20and%20cons.) raised in 2016, this is not possible.

`package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "minify": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0"
  }
```

My code:

```
import { minify } from 'minify';

const myFunction = () => {
  /* some code... */

  minify(filepath).then((file) => {
                    /* some code... */
  });
}
```

According to this [article](https://bunny.net/blog/why-optimizing-your-images-with-base64-is-almost-always-a-bad-idea/), in most cases, it is not neccessary to optimize images with `base64`. In my case some `css` files have grown to`10,000 KB` from `40-50 KB`, therefore I want to turn of `base64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to "turn off" `base64`.

The `minify` function accepts 2 parameters, `name` and `userOptions`.

The `userOptions` is passed down to `node_modules\css-b64-images\lib\css-b64-images.js`. There is the function called `replaceUrlByB64`, which does not encode to `base64`, if `maxSize` is smaller then the file size.

```
if (stat.size > options.maxSize){
      return cb(new Error('Skip ' + imageUrl + ' Exceed max size'), css);
}
```

My code:

```
import { minify } from 'minify';

/* Set image maxSize to 0 to skip url replacement by base64 in minify.
   node_modules/css-b64-images/lib/css-b64-images.js function: replaceUrlByB64 */
const skipReplacingUrlByB64 = {
    img : {
        maxSize: 0,
    },
}

const myFunction = () => {
  /* some code... */

  minify(filepath, skipReplacingUrlByB64).then((file) => {
                    /* some code... */
  });
}
```

The structure of `skipReplacingUrlByB64` object is based on how `userOptions` is retrieved in `node_modules\minify\lib\img.js`

```
const options = {
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...userOptions?.img || {},
};
```

`package.json` is the same as in the question

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "minify": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0"
  }
```